# Get FTP working with IPTables

Tags: linux, iptables

If i stop the IPTables service my ftp server works as expected. However, when enabled i am unable to connect (before authentication occurs).

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:rndc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             localhost           tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            anywhere            tcp dpt:sunrpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            anywhere            tcp dpt:imap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:ACK/ACK
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            helper match "ftp"
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ftp-data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a REJECT ALL and AFTER the accept for the ftp connection. Change your order !

Comment: +1. The order will be causing this. Also, you have a default policy of accept, and a bunch of accepting rules. You'll likely want iptables -P INPUT DROP , and then allow all expected traffic.